# Owl Carousel with jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, carousel

I am trying to make the elements in my Owl carousel draggable but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my set up:

HTML:

```
<div id="owl" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="my-owl-item"></div>
        <div class="my-owl-item"></div>
        <div class="my-owl-item"></div>
</div>
```

JS / jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
        //init carousel
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay:false,
            rewindSpeed:500,
            navigation:false,
            pagination:false,
            slideSpeed:1500,
            mouseDrag:false
        });

        //set up draggable
        jQuery( '.my-owl-item' ).draggable({
            start: function( event, ui ) {console.log('dragging');},
            helper : 'clone'
        });
});
```

I have disabled mouse dragging for the carousel because I though this might be the cause. The draggable start function is being fired - it outputs the debug message to the console as expected. The element is also being cloned too. So all seems to work except I can't drag it!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It's great that you've found your own solution, but you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @user3065931 I am also having the exact same problem.
I have some items in a carousel and I want these items to be dragable, so that I can drag them around and drop them somewhere else.

If you have a solution, then please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik I never managed to get this to work properly. The answer from @HarmanPreet is pretty close. I don't have their edited file anymore. They are right that you will need to enable dragging on the y axis as well as x. Plus you will need to disable the overflow setting on `.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer` when you start dragging so you can drag it outside the boundaries of the carousel. This caused a few display issues and some movement of elements. It worked but was not a suitable solution for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to edit the `owl-carousel.js` file to work perfectly with the draggable event because in `owl-carousel.js` by default it is only draggable in x direction. as i edited the js file so you can achieve the functionality you are looking for.
Here is the link to the Edited js file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lia6kkeimka94o/owl.carousel.js

and in you jquery where you are initializing the Owl-carasoul , Just remove the `mouseDrag` event.and also place the jquery ui at the end of the body tag. h

Here is my configuration

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var owl = $("#owl-demo");

      owl.owlCarousel({

        // Define custom and unlimited items depending from the width
        // If this option is set, itemsDeskop, itemsDesktopSmall, itemsTablet, itemsMobile etc. are disabled
        // For better preview, order the arrays by screen size, but it's not mandatory
        // Don't forget to include the lowest available screen size, otherwise it will take the default one for screens lower than lowest available.
        // In the example there is dimension with 0 with which cover screens between 0 and 450px

        itemsCustom : [
          [0, 2],
          [450, 4],
          [600, 7],
          [700, 9],
          [1000, 10],
          [1200, 12],
          [1400, 13],
          [1600, 15]
        ],
        navigation : true

      });



    });
    </script>
```

and

```
<script>
jQuery( '.item' ).draggable({
start: function( event, ui ) {console.log('dragging');}
});
</script>
```

and for the head tag

```
<!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
    <link href="../owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and the html markup is

```
<div id="demo">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

          <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>11</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>12</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>13</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>14</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>15</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>16</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>17</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>18</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>19</h1></div>
          <div class="item"><h1>20</h1></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I inspect your code and found that in your configuration of Owl carousel JavaScript.
You have written `mouseDrag:false` . because if you mention the `MouseDrag: False` , you will not be able to drag them with your mouse I have created my own jsFiddle with your provided code . Everything start working after i remove `mouseDrag:false`. [http://jsfiddle.net/datechogeek/ggTnW/](http://jsfiddle.net/datechogeek/ggTnW/) And make sure you are setting up the Owl Carousel as per the documentation provide by OwlGraphics [www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear. I don't want to drag the carousel. This is a feature turned on by default. So not an issue. What I want to do is use the jQuery UI draggable(); on the elements inside the carousel. So: click and drag one of the elements somewhere else in the page.

Comment: let me give you the complete access to my code [Owl.CarouselCustomized](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlj5j94r70dw1uv/owl.carouselCustomized.zip)

Comment: your example almost worked for me, however it calculated wrongly the ui-helper position! :/

Comment: Actually i didn't calculated it , wasn't the requirement of the question. Anyway thanks for trying and pointing it out.

Comment: @HarmanPreet the dropbox link to "complete access to my code" is broken, can you please provide me an accessible link?

Comment: This solution worked to a point for me. You need to disable the `overflow:hidden` property for `.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer` to drag outside of the carousel wrapper.