# Owl Carousel Drag and Drop elements from carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, owl-carousel

I'm working on a project using Owl Carousel and JQuery UI.
I would have a carousel of items a user can scroll through. Each item in the carousel would be draggable, and droppable to a droppable space below the carousel.
The issue i'm having is that the draggable object from the carousel is contained in the carousel boundaries. So that when i drag something out, the image is stuck within the boundaries but i'm able to successfully get the drop mechanism to recognize the selection.

There is another thread that had a solution but they never posted the final solution.
[Owl Carousel with jQuery UI Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581895/owl-carousel-with-jquery-ui-draggable)

I just need to be able to free the images in the carousel from the confines of the carousel containment